# How to set custom offline storage path from Javascript in QtQuick?

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, qml, qt-quick

I am working on a small QtQuick 2.0 project and using Offline Storage API to access a local sqlite database.
Here's how I connect to the DB:

```
LocalStorage.openDatabaseSync("myDatabase", "1.0", "description", 50000000)
```

Turns out, the `myDatabase` file should be stored at a predefined location: `~/.local/share/Nokia/QtQmlViewer/QML/OfflineStorage/Databases/`

My question is, how do I change this default path to the project folder path where I've kept the db file?
I've looked it up and could only get the C++ function for setting a custom location for the database

`void setOfflineStoragePath (const QString & dir)`

How do I set the custom database folder path for this single application from Javascript? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the offline storage path from a pure QML application is impossible since there is no equivalent to `QDeclarativeEngind::setOfflineStoragePath` available.

You can make additional C++ functionality available to QML, see [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qtqml-cppintegration-topic.html) how to do it. But if you introduce a C++ part in your application you could easily just set the storage path from there in the first place.

Comment: We can set the offlineStoragePath in QML using the engine()->setOfflineStoragePath() method

Comment: How would you do that? The only possibility – I am aware of – setting the offlineStoragePath inside QML is setting the QmlEngine as context property like `engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("qmlEngine", &engine);` in your cpp file and using it in your QML file like `qmlEngine.offlineStoragePath = 'foo'`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I know this has been a long time ago... but, for reference, I'll post my solution.

I had the same problem and a lot of confusion between AppDataStorage and OfflineStorage.

In the Main.cpp

```
  QQmlEngine qqEngine; //Creates an engine to fetch the OfflineStoragePath
 const QString dataFolder = qqEngine.offlineStoragePath(); 
 //Sets the Database folder
 QDir dir(dataFolder+"/Databases");

if (!dir.exists()) {
    dir.mkpath(".");
}
//Encrypt the database name with MD5, default from Qt
QString new_name = QString(QCryptographicHash::hash(("DatabaseName"),QCryptographicHash::Md5).toHex());
//Pick the source DB to be copied to the new location with the MD5 name
QFile file(":/DatabaseName.sqlite");
file.copy(dataFolder+"/Databases/" + new_name + ".sqlite");
file.close();
//The Sqslite must have a ini file with the database version and metadata in the same folder, so we also copy this file
QFile fileIni(":/databaseName.ini");
fileIni.copy(dataFolder+"/Databases/" + new_name + ".ini");
fileIni.close();
```

This worked like a charm for me. I hope this can help someone else.

A sample Ini file:

[General]

Description=Test Database

Driver=QSQLITE

EstimatedSize=1000000

Name=TestDB

Version=1.0